# How to change the font of side bar in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, macos-mojave

I am using Ayu Mirage theme with Solarized dark color scheme for Sublime Text 3. I have the following settings added. But the side bar font is not changing.

```
"ui_big_tabs": false,
"ui_fix_tab_labels": true,
"ui_font_default": false,
"ui_font_roboto_mono": false,
"ui_font_size_small": true,
"ui_font_source_code_pro": true,
"ui_native_titlebar": true,
"ui_separator": true,
"ui_wide_scrollbars": false,
```

I have source code pro and roboto mono fonts installed. I am using macOS Mojave. How to set a monospace font for the sidebar. Is it possible to set Monaco?

[image: screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open *Sublime Text* and and go to `Preferences -> Browse Packages...`. From there, open **User** folder and create file called same as your theme, `ayu-mirage.sublime-theme` .

To modify sidebar labels, write in file:

```
[
    {
        "class": "sidebar_label",
        "color": [255,255,255],
        "font.face": "Monaco"
    }
]
```

Using *JSON*, you can modify sidebar labels with [Font properties](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/themes.html#font_properties) and [Shadow properties](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/themes.html#shadow_properties).